# SiteMap and multiple providers

Tags: sitemap, provider

I have several sitemap providers(default, admin, etc) and run into a problem when I am using the admin provider. The root node always shows the home page of the default provider instead of the admin provider. Any ideas why and how this can be fixed?

```
<siteMap defaultProvider="default" enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="default"
              description="Default SiteMap provider."
              type="BLL.CustomSiteMapProvider"
              siteMapFile="~/Web.sitemap"
              securityTrimmingEnabled="true" />
    <add name="AdminXmlSiteMapProvider"
              description="Admin SiteMap provider."
              type="BLL.CustomSiteMapProvider"
              siteMapFile="~/admin/admin.sitemap"
              securityTrimmingEnabled="true" />
    <add name="FooterXmlSiteMapProvider"
              description="Footer SiteMap provider."
              type="BLL.CustomSiteMapProvider"
              siteMapFile="footer.sitemap"
              securityTrimmingEnabled="true" />
  </providers>
</siteMap>
```

Comment: I think you're going to have to get a bit more specific on what you want, what you've tried so far, and on which part you have problems. It also wouldn't hurt to tell us which technologies and environment you are using.  With the current information, the only answer I can give to your question is "no".

Comment: Have you tried changing the default Provider?

Comment: Then i would still have the same problem..i would have the admin root node in the default sitemap.